# Reset Password - Skip validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I need to skip the zipcode validation during the password reset action. What i have written so far is as follows.

User.rb

```
attr_accessor :email_confirmation, :user_role, :unit_user_property,
            :skip_validation, :skip_zip_validation, :login

validates_format_of :zip,
                  with: /\A\d{5}-\d{4}|\A\d{5}\z/,
                  message: 'should be of the format 12345 or 12345-1234',
                  unless: :skip_zipcode_validation?

# Return true/false to validate zipcode
# Skips validation if this returns true
def skip_zipcode_validation?
  skip_validation.present? || skip_zip_validation.present?
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected



  def configure_permitted_parameters
    added_attrs = [:phone, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :skip_zip_validation]

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(added_attrs) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(added_attrs) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(added_attrs) }
  end
```

app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb

```
<%= f.hidden_field :skip_zip_validation, value: true %>
```

But i am still getting the zipcode validation error on password reset. 
On debugging, the attribute skip_zip_validation is showing as nil. It looks like the attribute is not getting assigned to the user

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this fixed by overriding the devise reset_password_by_token method.

```
def self.reset_password_by_token(attributes={})
  original_token       = attributes[:reset_password_token]
  reset_password_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :reset_password_token, original_token)

  recoverable = find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:reset_password_token, reset_password_token)
  recoverable.skip_zip_validation = true
    if recoverable.persisted?
      if recoverable.reset_password_period_valid?
        recoverable.reset_password(attributes[:password], attributes[:password_confirmation])
      else
        recoverable.errors.add(:reset_password_token, :expired)
      end
    end

  recoverable.reset_password_token = original_token if 
  recoverable.reset_password_token.present?
  recoverable
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `:skip_zip_validation` is passed through as a permitted parameter.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    update_attrs = [:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password:, :skip_zip_validation]
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit :account_update, keys: update_attrs
  end
end
```

Comment: one debugging, the attribute skip_zip_validation is showing as nil